# Why do I keep dying after resetting Better Vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On returning to my game to do more vampire quests, I find that the vampires in Volkihar are repulsed at my being mortal again.
They tell me to see Serana to turn me into a vampire once again, but there's no dialog from her to do this.
I still look like a vampire, but no one acknowledges me as one.

The main problem is that whenever I try to reset Better Vampires ("a highly customizable vampire overhaul" mod), I die after the notification says "No vampirism is detected".
This also happens when I see Falion to cure me of vampirism. When he finishes the ritual and after I turn mortal, I die again.

I have no souped-up enchantments equipped that increases my health or anything of that nature.

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: Of course, I have mods installed???
Do you think  BV is the only mod I have?

Comment: Hey @ZadekielSephirah, there’s no need to be snarky in responses. Given how you didn’t specify whether or not you do have more mods installed, we as a community need to know to provide helpful answers. Since mods can lead to unforeseen experiences, especially when multiple are installed, the more we know the better :)

Comment: No problem!  lol
That was just the most unusual and obvious question to ask.

Comment: @ZadekielSephirah it is not, lots of people play without mods. Could you list your mods in your question? It could be that mods are the cause of your problem.

Comment: Basically, you are no vampire as far as the game is concerned. It looks like you need to be a vampire to be able to reset the mod, but you can't become one. It sounds like a typical heavy-script mod bug. Do you have any older saves you can test, to see how far back it reaches?

Comment: One problem resolved.
I had to go back 20 saves to be able to feed again and appear as a vampire to the Volkihar clan.
I think the problem was that when I saw that I kept dying that maybe my health was somehow depleted and didn't reset.
So I went into the console and click on my character and resurrected myself hoping to get a new start on health.
That may have separated my original self from being a vampire.
So I'm back to normal as far as being a vampire.
The MAIN problem is that when I have Falion cure me of vampirism, I die.
I also die when I reset Better Vampires and become mortal.